# Is there a way of changing a section of content in a file using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a file that I use as a template, which is copied over to each one of my customer folders. I manually go into the file and edit one line `EarNotch=5/5` to `EarNotch=13/6`. Is there a way I can add it to my current PowerShell script that copies over the file that would edit the file with the new unique ID that I require for this customer?

The file type I am working with is a .xml file. The EarNotch is always on Line 2.  Let me know what else you might need to know to help me figure this out.

Comment: If you post your script and what you have tried so far, we'll be able to help a lot quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to load the xml file using Get-Content, replace the string, then cast as xml so you can consume properly. This should answer your question.

```
$fileContents = Get-Content -Path C:\path\to\file.xml
[xml]$xmlFile = $fileContents.Replace('EarNotch="5/5"','EarNotch="13/6"')
```

For anything more complex, you might want to use XQuery, or other xml parsing.

Without knowing the structure of your xml file, the people on stack overflow can't help you. It's always best to post as much info as possible.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

Comment: #Code in the .xml file I want to change
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dcc:Job xmlns:gp="http://namespaces.globalplatform.org/systems-profiles/1.1.0" UniqueID="555554445545544" ProfileVersion="1.0.0" xmlns:dcc="http://www.datacard.com/gpProfiles">
  <gp:Description>Customer_Name_Here</gp:Description>

Comment: #Code to edit the xml fileContents
$CUST= Read-Host 'Enter Full Name of Customer'
$Unique= Read-Host 'Enter the New Unique ID'

#Edit the Template to Customer Name and OID ID
$fileContents = Get-Content -Path "$ScriptPath\$CUST\Project\$CUST.xml"
[xml]$xmlFile = $fileContents.Replace('UniqueID="555554445545544"','UniqueID="$($Unique)"')
[xml]$xmlFile = $fileContents.Replace('Customer_Name_Here','$CUST')